# XXX "is bound to a notation that does not denote a reference" during unfold in Coq?

Tags: coq

I am working on an example given [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Types.html):

```
Notation step_normal_form := (normal_form step).
Definition stuck (t:tm) : Prop :=
  step_normal_form t /\ ~ value t.

Example some_term_is_stuck :
  exists t, stuck t.
```

and I am having trouble `unfold`-ing the definition `step_normal_form` at step 1 (Coq 8.4pl6). I can `Check` its contents in CoqIDE:

```
normal_form
     : relation ?23 -> ?23 -> Prop
value
 : tm -> Prop
```

But when I unfold `step_normal_form`:

```
Example some_term_is_stuck :
  exists t, stuck t.
Proof.
  unfold stuck. unfold step_normal_form.
```

I get an error:

```
Error: step_normal_form is bound to a notation that does not denote a reference.
```

**Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?**

BTW, I tried to work around this by doing the `unfold` manually and redefining:

```
Definition stuck' (t:tm) : Prop :=
  normal_form step t /\ ~ value t.
```

and use `stuck'` instead. But Coq seems to automatically fold the content of `stuck'` into `step_normal_form` and then refuse to `unfold` it, giving the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Since `step_normal_form` is just notation for `(normal_form step)` you could just do `unfold normal_form.`

Sometimes notations and pretty-printing hides what's really there. Use `Set Printing All.` to [make Coq print the term in clear](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#sec130).